# adding a js library (not yet in typings) to an ionic2 project

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, camanjs

I'm trying to use this external javascript library [CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/) with my Ionic2 (typescript project)

I've found several articles like [this](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-typings/) and [this](http://x-team.com/2016/06/include-javascript-libraries-in-an-ionic-2-typescript-project/), however all of them assumes the library that is going to use is in [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings)

But CamanJS is not yet in the typings and there is a open [ticket for it](https://github.com/typings/registry/issues/328)

my question is, is there a way to add an external js library (which is not yet added to typings) to an ionic2 (typescript) project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me describe this process in a common case:

1. To include a JavaScript library in your TypeScript application you must first include it in your HTML file as a script tag.

   `<script src="js/your_external_library.js"></script>`
2. To use the library you must add the following to one of your `ts` files:

   `declare var libraryVar: any;`
3. Replace `libraryVar` with a variable, function, or class within your JavaScript library.

***At this point it is ready for use.***

4. After these steps you can use your external library with API which it provides. For example:

   `this.libraryVar = new libraryVar(parameters);`
5. Call `tsc` and `.ts` file compiled into `.js` with properly syntax and with your external library.

Comment: hey @alex , thanks for and answer and sorry for the delay on replying, I'll try this over this weekend and see how it goes. (Of course will accept if works ;) )

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to get it working with the help of you and sebaferreras. My new question with some more details is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061305/using-a-normal-js-librarary-with-ionic2-typescript/39061346#39061346)